# Is "experience" plural or singular

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, singular-vs-plural, grammaticality-in-context

Is it grammatically correct to use the word `experience` to mean multiple experiences, and follow it by a verb without adding `s`. For example:

> Experience show that most people ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct to use the word *experience* to mean multiple experiences.

But in your sentence *show* would be *shows*.

> Experience **shows** that most people ...

Answer (score 1):

The plural of "experience" is "*experiences*".

"Experience" can never mean more than one experience, but it can be used to describe a person or group's *collective* experience.

For example, on a résumé or curriculum vitae one might say "I have experience in [a particular field]" and refer to experience gained over many years and across several different job roles. If a team or a group have gained experience of a subject you can speak collectively of "*their* experience".

So, if you are referring to different experiences, either isolated incidents that one person experienced, or those of more than one individual, you would be correct to say:

> Experiences show that most people...

However, if you are referring to just one experience or your own collective experience you should use the word in singular form **but** the word "show" needs to be plural:

> Experience *shows* that most people...